# How can I create a one-off address to receive a USDT payment on the BSC or MATIC network?

Tags: web3js, polygon, payments, usdt

I want people on my Node.js website to be able to buy my products with USDT, so I'm trying to set it up with **web3.js**.
When users want to make a payment, I want them to select a network (such as BSC or MATIC) and I will then generate them a one-off address to which they will send their payment with whatever platform they use (Binance, Metamask, ...).

I will then have a routine that will periodically check that USDT has been sent on this address and once it is detected, I will mark their payment as complete and send the money from their one-off account to my main wallet.

So far, I've come up with this, but I'm still confused where the network (BSC, Matic) comes into play. I cannot find any examples of what I'm trying to do and given that I will probably have to use real money, I am a little skittish to make lots of tests.

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/XYZ'));
const account = web3.eth.accounts.create();
const usdtContractAddress = '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7';
const usdt = new web3.eth.Contract(???, usdtContractAddress, { from: ??? });

// Not sure what to put here
```

Also, I have generated an Ethereum account using the above, but my Infura dashboard still shows that I have made no request.

Thank you!

Comment: Well creating an account does not require any transaction/call as it's just a "mathematical operation". Just store the public key to do the checks and the private keys somewhere so you can access them later and you are done.